# Styling the titles in Vaadin Charts

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

In Vaadin Charts 2 (just released 2014-12), how can I style the title and subtitle of the charts?

The default font size is huge. I am showing multiple charts per layout, so I cannot afford so much space wasted on titling.

Is there some command or some CSS hooks for controlling the titles’ font size and margin/padding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Theme

The various [`Theme`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/style/Theme.html) controlling the look of the charts vary widely in their sizing. The new Valo themes ([`ValoLightTheme`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/themes/ValoLightTheme.html) and [`ValoDarkTheme`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/themes/ValoDarkTheme.html), matching Vaadin’s new [Valo](http://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!common) theme) tend to be much larger than the previous default, [`VaadinTheme`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/themes/VaadinTheme.html) (matching Vaadin’s [Reindeer](http://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme) theme).

So one easy way to change sizes of chart labels is to switch themes. The theme is not set on the individual chart. Instead, use a global setting affecting all charts within a [`UI`](https://www.vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html) (a web browser’s particular window/tab/portlet). The [`ChartOptions`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/ChartOptions.html) class has a [`setTheme`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/ChartOptions.html#setTheme(com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.style.Theme)) method.

```
ChartOptions.get().setTheme( new VaadinTheme() ); // All charts within a UI share the same Theme object.
```

Unless you have a specific need, I suggest putting that code in the `init` method of your `UI` subclass (such as `MyVaadinUI` in Vaadin projects created by Maven or the Vaadin Plugin for NetBeans/Eclipse).

## `Title` Object > `Style` Object

In [Vaadin Charts](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts) 2, the title and subtitle of the chart are represented by appropriately named objects, [`Title`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Title.html) and [`Subtitle`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/SubTitle.html). Each has an optional [`Style`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/style/Style.html) object. That object has several settings correlating to the usual CSS properties, including:

- font family
- font size
- color

### Font Size

So setting the font size is a matter of fetching:

> Chart object > Configuration object > Title object > Style object

…and then passing a string value for text size to the [`setFontSize`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/style/Style.html#setFontSize(java.lang.String)) method.

Seems simple, but there is one catch. The Style object is optional. By default, it does *not* exist. In other words, the `Style` object is meant for you and I to override the already-defined internal formatting.

So you must first check for the `Style` object’s existence, and if null, instantiate it.

Example code using [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) 7.3.7 with the fresh new ([as of 2014-12](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-charts-2-0-released)) Vaadin Charts 2 in Java 8.

```
final Configuration configuration = chart.getConfiguration();  // As per usual, interact with the chart via its Configuration object.
Title t = configuration.getTitle();  // Obtain the object representing the title (or Subtitle for subtitle).
if ( t.getStyle() == null ) {  // If not yet existing…
    t.setStyle( new Style() );  // Instantiate a Style object and install on the Title object.
}
Style st = t.getStyle();  // Obtain the Style object (whether new or pre-existing).
st.setFontSize( "0.5em" );  // Half an em is teeny-tiny, but demonstrates this approach works to change the font size.
```

## Left-Right Alignment

To set the title’s alignment towards the left or right of the chart, no need for the `Style` object. The `Title` object itself has a [`setHorizontalAlignment`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/AbstractTitle.html#setHorizontalAlign(com.vaadin.addon.charts.model.HorizontalAlign)) method. Pass values defined by the [`HorizontalAlign`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/HorizontalAlign.html) enum for LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT.

```
final Configuration configuration = chart.getConfiguration();  // As per usual, interact with the chart via its Configuration object.
Title t = configuration.getTitle();  // Obtain the object representing the title (or Subtitle for subtitle).
t.setHorizontalAlign( HorizontalAlign.LEFT );
```

## Legend

The legend is similar to `Title`. The `Configuration` contains a [`Legend`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Legend.html) object. The `Legend` contains a [`Style`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/style/Style.html) object.

> Chart object > Configuration object > Legend object > Style object

### Legend Item

The items (marker & series name) in a Legend have their own styling. To change the font or font size of those series names, access the items’ Style object. The catch is that there is no layer of "LegendItem" object. Instead of accessing such an object, call the `Legend` method [`getItemStyle`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/Legend.html#getItemStyle().)

> Chart object > Configuration object > Legend object > `getItemStyle` method